# Appcelerator Titanium wont build projects (after time machine restore)

Tags: build, compilation, titanium, appcelerator

```
Ti.SDK 1.6.2
iOS 4.3
```

I recently got a new system and built it off of a time machine backup of my old system.

When I try to compile and run any app in the simulator I'm getting the following error returned to the console.

```
[INFO] One moment, building ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.2/iphone/builder.py", line 1342, in <module>
main(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.2/iphone/builder.py", line 505, in main
link_version = check_iphone_sdk(iphone_version)
File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.2/iphone/builder.py", line 48, in check_iphone_sdk
output = run.run(["xcodebuild","-showsdks"],True,False)
File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.2/iphone/run.py", line 7, in run
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1106, in _execute_child
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It worked fine yesterday on the old system. I ran a backup before transferring and then installed the new system off of the most recent backup. Not sure why it would work on the old system and not the new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling xcode as the error referenced python. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting everything in build/iphone.  Do NOT delete the build/iphone directory, just everything IN it.  Restart Ti Studio and rebuild.